# Lambda expression in IF condition

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, lambda

I have following classes:

```
public class GetAdditionalProductCatalogResponse
{
    public List<AdditionalProductDetail> AdditionalProductDetail { get; set; }
}

public class AdditionalProductDetail
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string ServiceType { get; set; }
    public List<AdditionalProduct> AdditionalProduct { get; set; }
}
```

I have an want `GetAdditionalProductCatalogResponse` object and I want to check in an if condition whether an `AdditionalProductDetail` exists whose `ServiceType = "Phone"`. Is it possible?

```
//if(getAdditionalProductCatalogResponse.AdditionalProductDetail.Where)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `.Any(lamdaHere)`.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks

Comment: Note:
It doesn't make sense to have a class called "GetAdditionalProductCatalogResponse". That name sounds more like a method. Class names should be a noun phrase

Comment: @lhsoftware Noted :)

Comment: @lhsoftware It *is* a noun phrase. It's a class that encapsulates the response from the `GetAdditionalProductCatalog` operation. It's a common enough pattern, especially with auto-generated Request/Response messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Where` clause on an `IEnumerable` returns a filtered `IEnumerable`, which isn't a boolean expression - can't be used in an `if` statement. So what you need to do is check if there are `any` items in that collection - using the `Any` method:

```
if (products.AdditionalProductDetail.Where(...).Any())
```

which returns true/false.

There's a shorter syntax, using the `Any()` overload which takes a predicate and does the Where itself:

```
if (products.AdditionalProductDetail.Any(...))
```